# VS 2022 Not showing red squiggles under errors

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Looks as though IntelliSense also does not catch the error as you can see in the screenshot. I have the red squiggles enabled under Tools > Options > Text Editor > General

[image: VS no errors]

Comment: There could be a problem with the design time build.  See if this helps? https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/main/docs/design-time-builds.md#diagnosing-design-time-builds

Comment: You ever figure this out, I just got hit by it and it's annoying as I fat finger things all the time.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Resharper 2022.3.2 and the highlighted setting was checked. Unchecking solved this problem for me. [image]

Comment: I *LOVE* dotCover, but typically disable most of the ReSharper features.  This one bugged the heck out of me!

Answer (score 1):

Work-around: Renaming the '.VS' (i.e. to '.OLDVS') folder resets your project so the squiggles re-appear. For a while that is. Check-in your code before you rename the folder.

Had the same fault in VS2019. I sent in a test project, which was investigated but the error wasn't found.

Note:
I was using VS2019  and TFS2015(Azure DevOps) with a LOT of solutions under one project. TFS source control explorer workspace was set to 'LOCAL' which produced a .TF file >14GB which in turn meant every compile spent 1-2 minutes repositioning local disk data. I suspect this also had an impact on the missing squiggles error.